# Quickpay : An unknown error happened. Please try again

Tags: javascript, node.js, quickpay

I'm currently trying to complete a test payment on a Quickpay integration. I successfully generate a redirect url via the API like so,

**POST** https://api.quickpay.net/payments

**BODY**

```
{
    "order_id": "A4asdB2343", // This is generated at random each request
    "currency": "EUR",
    "variables": {
        "myCustomOrderId": 123
    }
}
```

**HEADERS**

```
{
    'Accept-Version': 'v10',
    Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(`:${authToken}`).toString('base64')}`,
}
```

Which returns

```
{
    "id": 145359050,
    ...
}
```

Which I then generate a redirectUrl request which looks like,

**PUT** https://api.quickpay.net/payments/145359050/link

**BODY**

```
{
    "amount": 400,
    "continue_url": "myurl",
    "cancel_url": "myurl"
}
```

**HEADERS**

```
{
    'Accept-Version': 'v10',
    Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(`:${authToken}`).toString('base64')}`,
}
```

Which returns

```
{
    "url": "https://payment.quickpay.net/payments/..."
}
```

I then redirect to the returned address.

Once on the payment page I try to complete the transaction with the [Credit card test numbers](https://learn.quickpay.net/tech-talk/appendixes/test/) but get the error message on submission.

[image]

I know the test cards work as per the example [here](https://quickpay.net/uk/demonstration) and I've added a payment method for `VISA` like so,

[image]

[image]

I'm assuming I've miss-configured my store? Has anyone run into an issue like this?

Comment: Could you please post your code so that someone would be able to identify the issue if there's any with your code?

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan payload examples are above. It would be great if it was an API issue but I'm doubtful as all the requests actually pass before the redirect url is created. If there was an issue with the parameters supplied I would expect to see the requests return an error message.

It also looks like the cancel and continue urls are optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you activated test transactions in the Quickpay manager (https://manage.quickpay.net/account) in Settings > Integration?

And did you remember to activate an acquirers with blank info ?

Also you dont need to set "visa" in "default payment methods" if you leave it blank it use every payment methods you have available

Comment: Thanks for this man. I should have resolved this when we solved it. You're right, the defaults aren't important but the integrations need to be set up correctly :)

Comment: Hi, I am also doing the same but this is not working with VIPPS. I have enable the Vipps but still getting 'No available payment-method for transaction' but its working with Clearhaus and other payment methods.any clue how to enable VIPPS?

Comment: @awsmsid what are you trying, a test paymen in vipps?

i just need to understand what you are asking :)

Comment: I am trying to enable the VIPPS option in the QuickPay but when I am using the QuickPay URL for payment I am not getting the VIPPS option on the payment page.

Comment: @awsmsid and you have a VIPPS account set up ?, you can't do testing with VIPPS, you will need to have a live VIPPS and QuickPay account. to test it, it's a personal account so test accounts can't be created by QuickPay.